# string function with c

Tags: arrays, string

I'm trying to understand the case study below:

"Design and implement a program that reads text from the standard input, and writes a list of the distinct words that appear. Words may be limited to a maximum of 10 alphabetic characters. Assume that as many as 1,000 distinct words might appear."

However, there are a few lines in the code that I don't quite understand. Could someone help me understand what does the 2 commented lines in the getword() function do? I'm not quite sure why do I need to run a while loop even though there's no code within the loop. I tried removing the line and an error came up. As for the 2nd commented line, I'd appreciate it if you could explain what does it do? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string.h>


#define MAXCHARS 10
#define MAXWORDS 1000


typedef char word_t[MAXCHARS +1];

int getword(word_t W, int limit);

        
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    word_t one_word, all_words[MAXWORDS];
    int numdistinct=0, totwords=0, i, found;
    while (getword(one_word, MAXCHARS) != EOF) {
        totwords = totwords+1;
        found = 0;
        for (i=0; i<numdistinct && !found; i++) {
            found = (strcmp(one_word, all_words[i]) ==0);
        }
        if (!found && numdistinct<MAXWORDS) { 
            strcpy(all_words[numdistinct], one_word);
            numdistinct +=1;
        }
    }
    printf("%d words read \n", totwords);
    for (i=0; i<numdistinct; i++) {
        printf("word #%d is \"%s\"\n", i, all_words[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
    
        

int getword(char W[], int limit) {
    
    /* Extract a single word out of the standard input, of not more than limit 
    characters. Argument array W must be limit+1 characters or bigger. */

    int c, len = 0;

    /* 1. what does this while loop do? */
    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF && !isalpha(c)) {
    }
    if (c==EOF) {
        return EOF;
    }
    
    /* 2. what does this line mean? */
    W[len++] = c;

    while (len<limit && (c=getchar())!=EOF && isalpha(c)) {
        W[len++] = c;
        
    }
    
    W[len] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output

```
mary had a little lamb, little lamb, little lamb
mary had a little fourleggedwhitefluffything 

16 words read 
word #0 is "mary"
word #1 is "had"
word #2 is "a"
word #3 is "little"
word #4 is "lamb"
word #5 is "fourlegged"
word #6 is "whitefluff"
word #7 is "ything"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a common idiom. It searches for a character that is alpha or EOF.
2. Stores the alpha character received from (1) in W.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, if that's the case, shouldn't (2) be inside the while loop (1)? Since there's no code to execute within the while loop if the conditions are met, what happens if conditions are not met?

Comment: If the conditions of loop 1 are not met, it will continue until EOF, so it cannot go on forever. At EOF it returns with EOF causing the main to exit its loop. Once the first loop discovers a word character, the second loop collects characters until a non-word character.